# Creating a notification using javascript and do that when the server says so

Tags: javascript, web, client-side-scripting, server-side-scripting

I would like to create a bubble notification in the center of the page (without refreshing), and make that bubble unable to be closed.  I want the bubble to be able to somehow be enabled by the web server.  I have flexibility as to how the client and server connect.  The bubble doesn't need to (but can) remove any content, but it does need to cover the content.  I also need the bubble to appear if the user loads the page after the trigger has been activated.

Summary:

- after a server event, send a message to the client (somehow...)
- make a bubble in a client language to cover content of page (must scroll with screen)
- keep this bubble there until another server event happens

I'm sure this will help: server specs:
- Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)

What server and client code would I use to implement a connection like this?

Comment: What is your question? Do you expect us to implement this for you? That's not going to happen.

Comment: Im wondering what I would use to do this

Comment: JavaScript, something like ajax or websockets, and your server-side programming language of choice. Boom, done.

Comment: That is the basics of what I need to do, but how would I have Javascript receive a message from a server-side-script?  I know i've seen some usage of javascript loading another page and parsing it into  variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different things you could use. You should probably take a look at Node.js and websockets. Alternatively, you can check out some recent solutions, such as Angular.js (by Google) and Meteor. Good luck!